# estimation of a sample size for a pilot study

Tags: statistics

I am currently involved in a research project whilst being involved in a statistics programme and I can't quite understand what I have to do...so if anyone could help I would be so very grateful.

OK so < need to look at diurnal variation in cortisol levels and I need to estimate my sample size for a pilot study. I have looked at several studies and currently have 6 standard deviation values. How do I then convert this into a formula that can give me a sample size?

Probably a stupid question but can anyone help?

Many thanks.